# Can an app be restricted to access Internet

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app, I don't want this (only this) app to access Internet. Is there any option in the settings to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can not prevent it from accessing the internet completely. However, you can disable it from using mobile data. Go to Settings -> Network and scroll down.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a per-app setting.